# actions_intent_CANCEL not invoke when exit

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Having an issue where actions_intent_CANCEL was not invoke when the Google Home exits. Here is what I've done in Dialogflow:

1. Created an intent call "Good-Bye" with event `action_intent_CANCEL`.
2. I created two intents, one to play audio via SSML(`<speak><audio src='https://....'></audio></speak>`) and the other using mediaResponse.

Both plays audio just fine. The problem is when i say "stop", if mediaResponse is playing the audio, the audio stops and that's it. The `actions_intent_CANCEL` did not invoke.

however, if the audio was playing using the intent with SSML, and I say "stop", `action_intent_CANCEL` does get invoked.

What is happening and why the difference?

Answer (score 0):

This is how the platform behaves. Saying "Stop" in a MediaResponse does not exit your Action, it stops the media playback. If the user says "stop" a second time, that should be registered as a CANCEL intent.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I kind of figure so. I'm trying to find documentation this type of behavior. What's strange about it is that when I play it with SSML, I was able to say "stop" and it actually fires the CANCEL intent.

Comment: SSML is different than a media response.

Answer (score 0):

This is a longstanding a **severe** defect in how Media Response is handled.

[The documentation for Media Response](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/rich-responses#media_responses) *does* say

> Media responses support the following audio controls for voice interaction:
>
> [...]
>
> “Ok Google, stop.”

But *does not* further define what the implications are.
One could argue that one of these two things *should* happen

- It should raise a `actions_intent_MEDIA_STATUS` event with the `MEDIA_STATUS` value set to "finished"
- It should raise the `actions_intent_CANCEL` event

Unfortunately - neither happens. And the Action just sits there, waiting for the user to say something else, and violating [Google's design guidelines](https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/conversation/conversational-components/overview.html#overview-where-how-prompts-appear).

There is no workaround.